# Is there a way to use an array as an index in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, indexing

I'm trying to speed up my code and right now I have a "for" loop to sum numbers in an array. It's set up like this:

```
a1=np.zeros(5)
a2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And what I want to do is sum the values of `a2[:5]` + `a2[5:]`, to end up with

```
a1=[7,9,11,13,15]
```

So I've made a loop that goes:

```
for ii in range(2):
    a1+=a2[5*ii:5*(ii+1)]
```

However, this is taking really long. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this or how to restructure my code?

I want to do:

```
i=np.range(2)
a1+=a2[5*i:5*(i+1)]
```

But can't, since you can't use arrays as indices in Python. That's the only other idea I've had besides the loop.

Edit: the 2 here is just an example, in my code I'm planning on having it do this like 50-100 times.

Comment: I think you can convert the python list to np array to do what you want. If you want the final result as a python list, you can convert the np array to a python list too.

Comment: `a2[:5] + a2[5:]` does different things depending on whether  `a2` is a list or array.  `a1+=a2[....]` does summation because `a1` is an array,  If you initialed it as `[]` you'd get the list join.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you would like to add the first half of the list to its second half. This can be accomplished by reshaping the 1D list into a 2D array (2x5) and summing it along the horizontal axis.

```
np.array(a2).reshape(2,5).sum(axis=0)
# array([ 7,  9, 11, 13, 15])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you really want to achieve.
but the np.roll function might get the speed you are looking for:

```
a2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
a1 = a2[:5] + np.roll(a2, -5)[:5]
```